# Please suggest me best linux distro according to my PC specs

Tags: dual-boot, distro-recommendation

I am a Windows user so plz suggest easy and user-friendly distro.
I am a Student and switching mainly due to performance issue.
Also I will be dual booting Linux with Windows 11.

Here are my PC specs:
**Storage : 1 TB
Processor:  Intel(R) Core(TM) i3-7020U CPU @ 2.30GHz   2.30 GHz (Dual Core)
Installed RAM:  4.00 GB (3.87 GB usable)
System type:    64-bit operating system, x64-based processor
Display Resolution : 1366 x 786 HD+ Display
Graphics : Intel UHD 620(2GB internal)
Direct X 12**

I prefer Ubuntu more than any other distro but am unsure of getting a good deal of performance on my Low-end PC.

For more specs, refer:
https://support.hp.com/in-en/document/c06268109

Comment: Just about any modern distribution of Linux will run on your hardware. “Performance” is a relative term that means different things to different people, so cannot be answered without a great deal of opinion. Make some Live USBs of the different distros and give them a try. The one you enjoy the most can then be installed alongside Windows.

Comment: The only distributions that are on-topic here are Ubuntu and *flavors* of Ubuntu (https://ubuntu.com/download/flavours).  I'm using a 11 year old PC (before the i-series CPUs came out) & can run them all; but my tastes, the apps I want to run, RAM all play a part in what is best. Only you can really decide (and you gave no clues as to taste, what apps you want to run etc - though as this isn't a forum, that detail is off-topic here too - this is a Q&A site).

Comment: As per some of the links in the comments - (1) try it out with a live session to check it will run well in your system, but (2) my anecdotal experience is that any machine capable of running Windows 10 will run Ubuntu (and ‘better’) … the os seems so much lighter in terms of resource use, everything is faster. Yes it’s quite low spec, but I would be very surprised if your machine wouldn’t run the latest lts version of Ubuntu with no difficulty.

Comment: Your hardware is more than sufficient to run any popular Linux distro or any popular desktop environment.  It's not a "gaming PC" but it's perfectly capable of running a modern OS without breaking a sweat.

Answer (score 2):

So It just depends on you what you want, I can only suggest because your system specs are OK,  You can have any type of ubuntu flavour you want, Let me give you a brief Idea

You can find alternatives of ubuntu I.e ubuntu flavours [here](https://ubuntu.com/download/flavours)

---

## Lubuntu

A good Linux distro, If your PC isn't much good in specs then Lubuntu can help you to get maximum performance even from an ultra potato PC,  It also offers an OK GUI, It also comes with a handful of apps and stuff, So I guess it would be good for you PC specs,

[Official page of Lubuntu](https://lubuntu.me)

[Wikipedia Page of Lubuntu](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lubuntu)

---

## Xubuntu

Good for performance with very minimal memory usage, This is what is good and recommend for your PC.

It would be good in this case as you are not on a bad PC, It is just normal. Lubuntu is designed for a very minimal thing. But Xubuntu can help you as it is for the average PC and works well even with very good PCs

https://xubuntu.org/about/

---

## Kubuntu

Good for a beautiful GUI, It may cut off some performance but is beautiful. But as your specs it will not give much performance, So it's not for heavy use as per your specs but it is good if you are a GUI lover

More info can be found at

https://kubuntu.org/about-us/

---

## Ubuntu Vanilla

Good but I don't recommend it for your specs, Don't install it.

---

## I cannot tell you everything all about distros but you need to check out more about them yourself

---

## CONCLUSION

It depends on your admiring, every distribution is good, but I would personally recommend Xubuntu for you.

---

**There are many other distros too, check out Gentoo, mint, kali or Garuda, All these are just the best in their forms**

---

## "Every Distribution has its abilities"

---

Your specs are good enough to use any of them, So go ahead and pick one today.

Comment: you have no down-votes  (*that I can see*)

Comment: This post has no downvote https://prnt.sc/20xl09r

Answer (score 0):

Arch linux doesn't turn any services on by default, so Arch linux is faster than debian. But as you're a beginner, using a debian distro will be a safe bet, because of the bigger community and stable features. I'll suggest you to use linux mint which is a distro based on ubuntu but has better performance when used in older machines.
Research and take precautions about the dual boot, as windows update can cause some problems. And also avoid overwriting and take care of security issues. As you have 1 TB space so the partitions won't bother you I think.

Comment: Please refer https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic, Ubuntu and *official* flavors of Ubuntu (https://ubuntu.com/download/flavours) are on-topic on this site. The on-topic link provides alternate SE sites for non-Ubuntu OSes.

Comment: You mention performance & security issues, but also Linux Mint?  Linux Mint uses runtime *adjustments* which add an extra layer of software running in the stack (*thus slowing performance, not increasing it*) & adding extra security holes (*even if minor*)... let alone being off-topic on this site.

Comment: He's still a student, it's very unlikely that he'll find any friend using distro other than ubuntu, mint or pop. I think he'll dual boot windows because most of the courses will be shown using windows. If he's overwhelmed by a lot of distro at the beginning, then there is a fair chance that he'll not boot linux at all.